# mysql connection in qgis

Tags: mysql, qgis

I had just install Quantum GIS 1.8.0 on my Ubuntu 10 ,I Want To Add MySql Table as Source but No Options for connecting to mysql can Any One Guide me how to connect to mysql?

Options for Available Database Types in  Qgis are MSSQL,ODBC,PostgreSQL and ESRI Personal GEO Database.

Comment: It's better to ask gis and qgis realted questions on http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

To add a MySQL data table or vector layer just follow the procedure of adding a new vector layer:

```
Menu Layer > Add Vector Layer
```

Select Database as source type. Then you have to define a connection by clicking on New.

```
Type: Mysql
Name: your connection name
Host: remote or local IP address
Database: database name
Port: leave blank for default 3306
Username: mysql user
Password: mysql user's password
```

Click on Test connection to check if everything works fine, then OK. Your connection is saved and you are ready to use it: Select it from the drop down menu and click on Open.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Be careful, it looks like this was removed in QGIS 2.0. Worked fine in 1.8.

Comment: yes I don't see the MySQL option in 2.10-Pisa. How to view mysql table in qgis?

Comment: On v2.18.7 only ODBC, ESRI Personal geoDatabase, MSSQL and PostgreSQL are available. Can you post a screenshot @DPSSpatial?

Comment: @bradypus check that... using 2.18.4